# Not able to kill a process started in a script which is running on a device which is based on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, process, signals, arm

I am trying to kill or interrupt a script that is running on an arm device that is based on Ubuntu.

The script starts a program that has an infinite while loop after polling for an external trigger and hence never returns.

The script starts at the boot of the device and hence I have lost control over the device terminal and not able to run any command on the device.

Keyboard shortcuts for passing signals to the script and program are not able to stop that process. I am not able to change the script file as well. I am trapped in it.

Comment: What have you tried?
kill -9 PID# should kill it if you have command line access.

Comment: Try suspending it with CTRL + Z

Comment: I am not able to use command line as the program is running in the foreground. I tried killing it with ctrl+c,z,/. If I could remove the script from the device, this will help me but I am not able to do so.